# Connect SSL error in APNs with python

Tags: python, apple-push-notifications

I need to start python server for apple notification system. I trying to use diffrent libs from this link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=apns&submit=search

For example, apnsclient:

```
from apnsclient import *
import os

session = Session()
pem_file = os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'),'production.pem')
con = session.get_connection("push_sandbox", cert_file=pem_file)
```

raises exception:

```
 error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib
```

or:

```
 Error: [('PEM routines', 'PEM_read_bio', 'no start line')]
```

Other librarys raises similar exceptions.
Pem file is ok, cuse it was tested via push_me_baby application in mac.

What is the problem? Which package you recommend with python 2.7?

python 2.7. windows 7 x64 / ubuntu 12.04